# Passing object in action method laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

Is there any way I could pass an object through Redirect action method ?
For eg. `return Redirect()->action('projectController@create_project',$project);`

How to pass $project ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The second parameter of the **action** method will accept an array of parameters:

`return redirect()->action('ProjectController@create_project', ['project' => $project]);`

If you want to have this parameter only when redirecting, you can create the rote with an optional parameter:

`Route::get('admin/{project?}', ['uses' => 'ProjectController@create_project']);`

Then your method will look like this:

`public function create_project( $project = null ) { }`

When you don't have it in the route or if it's not passed from a redirect it'll be **null** otherwise you'll have your data in the variable.

Comment: how is this accessed in the other function ? as a parameter ? This has to pass through routes is it ?

Comment: To have access to this in **create_project** you would have to add is as a method parameter like this: `public function create_project( $project ) { ... }`. If **Project** is a model that you have you could bind it in the route https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding.

Comment: Its an array. How do I pass it through the route ?

Comment: Why do you want pass it through the route? You can't have an array in the URL. If you only need it when redirecting from another method add it as an optional parameter in the route deceleration. Otherwise make your route with an ID or slug.

Comment: yea but it says cannot pass array.